# What is the useState alternative for fast parallel, async state updates?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I'm trying to build a little calendar, where one can "mark" days by clicking on them.
Each click causes a request to the server to persist the change (set or unset a day).

It seems like `useState` can only keep up with so many changes at once, and due to the nature of reloading the component, i loose some of the fetch-requests happening as well.

When i understand the `useState` behavior correctly, each `setDays` will reload the whole `Calendar`, even if an instance still has a request running. The system is smart enought, so that a (limited) number of requests still manage to complete in the background and trigger their state update. However i have no control or guarantee over how many "make" it when clicking fast.

My real code has an additional state change, by marking/unmarking each day as "in flight" (via `dayClassName`) while the request is running, probably increasing the problem even more.

I'm a bit lost in what direction to go from here:

Should i try to limit the effect of a day change to a single day itself, avoiding to update the whole calendar with every click (need the result outside, though).
Or is a different system/strategy to manage the state, e.g. redux, the better choice here. For example to serialize the updates into one stream.

Update:

Here is a codesandbox with example: https://zpvy0.csb.app/

I tried to get as close to the real thing as possible, unfortunately i still can't reproduce the issue. It seems like react/useState is not the issue, as in the codesandbox it works reliable with 30+ requests triggered at once.

Update 2:

I have rewritten my code using the codesandbox version as base (re adding what other functionality/styling, etc was there). Now everything works perfectly.
Currently i have no idea what difference was causing it at the end.

Comment: Is the issue that `addDay` and `removeDay` are called in quick succession and you are losing some state updates?

Comment: Yes. When clicking on a few days, adding and removing in quick succession, it's the most visible.
But also when just adding several days at once, there seems to be a limit of how many "stick" before the component can't keep up

Comment: Have you considered decoupling the persistence handling from the view state handling? As in, send your requests to update the state, but don't wait for the result to update the view? Obviously this could fail when the server can't handle the request. At this point the view is no longer *in sync* with the server state. Though that might be a simpler problem to solve.

Comment: @Yoshi unfortunately i need a reliable confirmation/state in the client. It's ok if requests fail, but the client needs to reflect this.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it failing silently. Though you could split the processes. Have an indicator that signals when updates are made (pending, or in flight) and also when those succeded or failed (worst case). In case of an error you could request the user to reload the calendar before continuing.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know if I'm not clicking right but I don't see any duplication or omission of state updates in your CSB. I agree, I don't think React is the issue here. What else is your actual code doing? Is it your server having issues handling request loads?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your issue correctly it sounds like the issue is that `addDay` and `removeDay` are called in quick succession and you are losing some state updates. You mention users clicking "to fast" so it may be the case that more than 1 state update is being enqueued. Since you are using plain updates if 2 updates are enqueued within the same render cycle the second update overwrites the first. If more get enqueued then each subsequent processed update overwrites the previous. Hopefully you get the idea here.

The resolution for this is to use functional state updates so each enqueued and processed update updates from the previous state, not the state the update was enqueued in. This means if multiple updates are enqueued in a render cycle each update/change is applied sequentially and the result aggregated state update is available for the next render cycle.

[Functional Updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates)

> If the new state is computed using the previous state, you can pass a
> function to `setState`. The function will receive the previous value,
> and return an updated value.

The previous state is an array and you are updating *from* that array when appending new `day` objects. It's a very minor tweak.

```
const addDay = async (day) => {
  await makeRequest(day);
  setDays(days => [...days, day]);
};

const removeDay = async (day) => {
  await makeRequest(day);
  setDays(days => days.filter((d) => d !== day));
};
```

Comment: Thanks. This was my first though as well and one of the optimizations i tried, as mentioned (i'll update my question for clarity).
I think it improved the issue, loosing less updates (or later). But unfortunately did not resolve it.

Comment: @maxigs I see. Can you create a *running* codesandbox demo of your code that reproduces the issue that we could inspect and debug live? I don't see anything crazy in the code snippet posted in your question, but I don't know what `makeRequest` does and there may be something hidden in the `...` in your render return.

Comment: Here is one prepared https://zpvy0.csb.app/. However, so far it performs much better, only when rapidly clicking on one day i can cause duplicates show up. I will try to extend it with a bit more "real" interaction, but i think the stripped down example is just running much faster than my real calendar.

Comment: @maxigs That CSB appears to function without issue for me. I was never able to click and get any odd duplicates to occur. ‍♂️

Comment: indeed, the version rebuild from scratch worked without any issues, as i noted in the last update of my question. unfortunately i did never find that one source of the issue at the end :/

Comment: @maxigs Ah, I do see that additional comment now. Yeah, odd, but at least your code is in a better place now. Cheers and good luck.